# IF condition in Groovy

Tags: jmeter

Please could someone help me with this simple IF condition in Groovy? I have obtained a value (],) from a RegEx and am trying to use it in the subsequent groovy IF condition. I had the below which is not working:

${__groovy(vars.get("Results_Flag").contains("],"),)}

Comment: I tried using .equals also - not working

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape comma `,` with a backslash `\` so your condition should look like:

```
${__groovy(vars.get("Results_Flag").contains("]\,"),)}
```

Take a look at [JMeter Functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) documentation:

> If a function parameter contains a comma, then be sure to escape this with "", otherwise JMeter will treat it as a parameter delimiter.

If you take a look at [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) you should see something like:

> invalid variables in node If Controller
> org.apache.jmeter.functions.InvalidVariableException: __groovy called with wrong number of parameters. Actual: 3. Expected: >= 1 and <= 2

More information: [6 Tips for JMeter If Controller Usage](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-if-controller)